# Office 2003 Templates: Change default save location

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-2003

Whenever I open Office 2003 templates at work and save them, the default location is "My Documents".

How can I change this?

Comment: Which application?  They're all different.

Comment: @rjrapson: I was looking for Word and Excel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer for Word 2003 - on the Tools Menu, select Options.  Select the File Locations Tab, and modify the location for the user templates and/or workgroup templates.